# Tag Helper not picked up in Razor

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a Tag helper that works in a Razor project. I have copied it into a Blazor server project and that project has the name name as the Razor one. The Tag Helper is not being run. There are no build errors.

Previously, I would have said that @addTagHelper was missing but that isn't used in Blazor.

Are Tag Helpers used in Blazor? What is the replacement for @addTagHelper?

My Tag Helper starts like this (it is a grid navigation control)

```
namespace myapp.ui.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("pagenav")]
    public class PageNavigation : TagHelper
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer found. Tag Helpers don't existing in Blazor as they are Razor components.

[Razor pages breakdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)